# How to submit a form and execute javascript simultaneously

Tags: javascript, php, html

As a follow-up to my last question, I have run into another problem. I am making a project on google homepage replica. The aim is to show search results the same as google and store the search history on a database. To show results, I have used this javascript:-

```
        const q = document.getElementById('form_search');
        const google = 'https://www.google.com/search?q=';
        const site = '';

        function google_search(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        const url = google + site + '+' + q.value;
        const win = window.open(url, '_self');
        win.focus();
                    }
    
                    document.getElementById("s-btn").addEventListener("click", google_search)
```

To create my form, I have used the following HTML code:-

```
        <form method="POST" name="form_search" action="form.php">
      
        <input type="text" id="form_search" name="form_search" placeholder="Search Google or type URL">
```

The terms from the search bar are to be sent to a PHP file with the post method. I have 2 buttons. Let's name them button1 and button2. The javascript uses the *id* of button1 while button2 has no javascript and is simply a submit button.

The problem is that when I search using button1, the search results show up but no data is added to my database. But when I search using button2, no results show up( obviously because there is no js for it) but the search term is added to my database. If I reverse the *id* in javascript, the outcome is also reversed. I need help with making sure that when I search with button1, it shows results and also saves the data in the database. If you need additional code, I will provide it. Please keep your answers limited to javascript, PHP, or HTML solutions. I have no experience with Ajax and JQuery. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: "_submit a form and execute javascript simultaneously_" is not possible. Use AJAX to send the data to your server. "AJAX" is not a language, it's just a name for techniques used to make an HTTP request without leaving the current page. You can use AJAX via the native [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) object.

Comment: _Side note:_ There's no real reason to add a `name` attribute to the form tag itself. But if you do add it, it should be unique within the form. You've given the form and the input the same name, which is wrong.

Comment: you need to provide more code html and php with both buttons

Answer (score 0):

Tony since there is limited code available so go with what you had stated in your question.

It is a design pattern issue not so much as so the event issue.

Copy pasting from Wikipedia "software design pattern is a general, reusable solution to a commonly occurring problem within a given context in software design. It is not a finished design that can be transformed directly into source or machine code. Rather, it is a description or template for how to solve a problem that can be used in many different situations. Design patterns are formalized best practices that the programmer can use to solve common problems when designing an application or system."

So here is how things play out at present;

1. forms gets submitted to specific URL i.e. based on action attribute
2. Requested page gets Query sting in php and lets you play around with it

then from there on .....
3. either you get results from database and return response
4. or you put search request into database and return success response

Problem statement

if its 3 then search request is not added to database if its 4 then results in response to search request are not returned.

Solution

you need to combine both 3 and 4 in to one processing block and will always run regardless of the search query is.

So our design pattern could use mysql transaction so whole bunch of queries would run a single operation example

```
$db->beginTransaction(); // we tell tell mysql we will multiple queries as single operation 
$db->query('insert query');
$results= $db->query('search query');
$db->commit(); // if we have reached to this end it means all went fine no error etc so we commit which will make database record insert query into database. If there were errors then mysql wont record data.

if($results) {echo $results;} else {echo 'opps no result found';}
```

slightly more safe version

```
try {
    $db->beginTransaction(); // we tell tell mysql we will multiple queries as single operation 
    $db->query('insert query');
    $results= $db->query('search query');
    $db->commit(); // if we have reached to this end it means all went fine no error etc so we commit which will make database record insert query into database. If there were errors then mysql wont record data.

if($results) {echo $results;} else {echo 'opps no result found';}
} catch (\Throwable $e) {
    // An exception has been thrown must rollback the transaction
    $db->rollback();
    echo 'oho server could not process request';
}
```

We have effectively combined two query operation into one always recording into database and always searching in database.